# MySQL multi-column indexes and OR statement

Tags: mysql, indexing, multiple-columns

I found an [interesting SitePoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-mysql-application/) about indexes in MySQL

The above article talks about the "AND" statement, where a "SELECT" like

```
SELECT peopleid 
FROM people 
WHERE firstname='Mike' 
    AND lastname='Sullivan' 
    AND age=17
```

can take advantage of a multi-column indexing like

```
ALTER TABLE people 
    ADD INDEX fname_lname_age (firstname,lastname,age);
```

But in my web applications I have often a textfield input where the user can type portions of firstname or lastname, resulting in a query like this:

```
SELECT peopleid 
FROM people 
WHERE ((firstname LIKE '%$parameter%') 
        OR (lastname LIKE '%$parameter%')) 
    AND age=17
```

So, does the multi-column indexing improve performance also in cases like these?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a chapter in the official [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) especially for this.

But what you really should learn about is [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). Put it in front of your query like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT peopleid 
FROM people 
WHERE ((firstname LIKE '%$parameter%') 
        OR (lastname LIKE '%$parameter%')) 
    AND age=17
```

And you can see if an index is used or not.

Comment: Thanks about the chapter! Seems that the question to my answer is "no": different fields with "OR" cancatenation don't take advantage of multi-column indexes...